# Creation of threads in remote machine

Tags: java, selenium

I'm working on a selenium project where in one enhancement I used Threads for clicking of Alert boxes. It worked fine on my machine but now we have to implement this on a remote machine.

How do I create remote threads so that I can run this on the remote machine?

Comment: Maybe look at RPC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call

Comment: Selenium grid will work on web elements of remote machines but I want to know creation of threads on a remote machine in JAVA